Android Instant App. App Icons are not showing on all devices on 'recents' screen
I've built an Android Instant app. The app builds to an .aab app bundle, and is hosted on the Play Store.
Some users on specific devices have reported the App Icon is not displaying on the 'recents' screen. The 'default' Android icon is being displayed instead. The App Icon correctly appears everywhere else (in Settings > Apps > App list and App Details, for example).
How the Instant App looks on a 'problem' device (Samsung Galaxy A40)...

How the Instant App looks on a 'working' device...

PROBLEM DEVICES

Samsung Galaxy A40
Samsung Galaxy S20+
OnePlus Open

I've used BrowserStack to test on multiple different devices, and have not been able to replicate the problem with any of the devices available on BrowserStack.
Can anything be done to make the App Icon for an Instant App appear on the 'recents' screen consistently across all devices?

I've recreated the image assets and launcher icons with Asset Studio as per the documentation.
I've tried building the instant app as an .apk instead of an app bundle (.aab), and interestingly the icon displays correctly when manually installing the .apk on a problem Samsung Galaxy A40. The default Android icon is not displayed when the .apk is installed...

This is not the solution, as the app bundle is not instant enabled when building as a .apk, and I need the app to be an Instant App.
Here is the Android Manifest for the App...

I've also tried modifying the bundle settings in my build.gradle file, to disable splitting of the density and resources. I wasn't sure if the correct resources for the density of the 'problem' devices were correctly loaded.

